# python re.sub() with pair or characters

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to grab a string that is surrounded by "! and replace the first "!" with a "!_".

For example:
str(!test!).strip() -> str(!_test!).strip()

Here is the code I have so far:

```
print re.sub(r'!.*?!','!_', 'str(!test!).strip()')
```

With this code I grab too much and the result is:
str(!_).strip()

Any thoughts on how to zero in on the first "!". Or alternatively, is there a way to grab the string in the "!!" and then add "!_"+"!" arround that string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group the second half of the "word" with parenthesis and use the group in your substitute string `\g<1>`.

```
re.sub(r'!(.*?!)', '!_\g<1>', 'str(!test!).strip()')
```

Comment: Technically CharString's first solution is the one you want. I forgot that python had lookahead. It would be more efficient and understandable.

Answer (score 1):

```
print re.sub(r'!(?=.*?!)', '!_', 'str(!test!).strip()')
```

Uses a positive lookahead.

```
print re.sub(r'!(.*?)!', r'!_\1!', 'str(!test!).strip()')
```

Uses a backreference.

Answer (score 1):

Exclude `!` from the characters between the !s: use `[^!]` instead of `.`

Then, capture the part of the RE you want to keep with `()`, and in the replacement string, use `\1` to insert it again.

```
print re.sub(r'!([^!]*!)', r'!_\1', 'str(!test!).strip()')
```